# How many samples to get the accuracy to the Kth digits of Pi?

Tags: binomial-distribution, monte-carlo

Suppose we are using Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the pi. You draw $n$ random sample $(x,y)$ within $(-1,1)$ and you count the number of $x^2 + y^2 < 1$. If you want to estimate to the kth digits of Pi using this method, how many sample do you need? Is there a statistical way to give a boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The area of a Circle is $\pi\times r^2$ and the Area of a square on the coordinates $(\pm1 , \pm1)$ is $4$. The ratio of the area of the square indicated to the circle is $\pi/4$ because the radius of the circle is $1$. Now if we sample from the unit square and only accept the points inside the unit square we get accept the sample $\pi/4$ percent of the time ($\pi/4$ is less than $1$). A consistent and unbiased estimator is the sample mean of the the indicators (random variables that take the value $1$ when inside the circle) from this sampling scheme. The sample mean has variance $p(1-p)/n$ where $p=\Pr(X^2+Y^2<1)=\pi/4$. A rough approximation would be to say that the binomial variance, $p(1-p) < 1/4$, then use the multiplier of the normal distribution approximation to get $1.96$ to get an upper point of the confidence interval $\bar{x}_n + \frac{1.96}{4\sqrt{n}}$ to within your desired level of accuracy. Suppose your accuracy is $10^{-k}$ for some $k\in\{1,2,3,\dots \}$. Then bound the upper deviation of the confidence interval upper limit point to be less than the desired accuracy:

$$\frac{0.7}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 10^{-k}.$$

Solving the inequality for $k$ gives you $n \geq 0.49 \times 100^{k}$. If instead you prefer to use a more accurate approximation for $p=\Pr(X^2+Y^2<1)=\pi/4$, then replace $0.7$ above with $1.96\times p(1-p)$ and solve for $n$. Therefore here if you want $k=2$ digits of accuracy (at $95\%$ confidence) you need your sample to be greater than $0.49\times 100^2=4900.$ Note you might still be inaccurate $5\%$ of the time.